# How to see logs for ADF mobile application?

Tags: oracle-adf

I have deployed a sample application into Android emulator. Its executing, however its giving wrong output. **How to debug it??** and If error comes while opening the page in emulator, **where i can see the entire log??**

Regards
Raj

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, 'Testing and Debugging ADF Mobile Applications' :
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E35521_01/doc.111230/e24475/debugging.htm

Comment: Thank you .. and I have onemore doubt related to ADF mobile application, Recently i started to develop ADF on-device mobile application. Is it possible to use ADF webservice proxy client with on-device mobile application? I read it in a document that, ADF mobile wont support "WebService Java Proxy" and supports only "ADF webservice datacontrol"

If ADF webservice proxy client is not supported in ADF mobile, then how can i integrate ADF with EBS?